# How do I block from input with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Say I display a div through using jQuery, but I want the rest of the window (everything except that div) be unaccessible for user - so all the controls are disabled and the user can only do something with the controls in that special div?

Comment: demos are here http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos

Comment: as i said simple fix can be z-index///

Comment: I think you are looking for an [expose](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/toolbox/expose/index.html) effect.

Comment: I used fancybox. here it is http://fancybox.net

Comment: @everyone - thank you for all the answers, all the samples are great. So giving +1 to everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a [modal dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-modal) from your `<div>` element:

```
$("#yourDivID").dialog({ modal: true });
```

Comment: Learn something new every hour on SO :)

Comment: I get the Object does not support this property or method.

Comment: @Max, the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) framework defines the `dialog()` method (among [others](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)).

Answer (score 2):

Please use jquery bock UI plugin

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

for a simple fix , if your z-index of popup is greater than all the elements behind , you cannot touch the items behind

give z-index like 1000 or so

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for "jquery lightbox" and you will find what you are after, or use the jquery modal dialog as mentioned in another answer.

I like lightboxes as they overlay the page with an opacity mask, clearly showing the controls are disabled/not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using full blown plugins for something that is so simple:

Use a second div, whose css position is `fixed` and whose `width` and `height` is equal to the `window.innerHeight` & `window.innerWidth` properties respectively. Set the `z-index` to something large, but less than the `z-index` of the model dialog your showing.

```
$('<div />').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    'z-index': 1000
});
```

As mentioned in the comments however, this does not stop the users tabbing to the hidden fields; to do that, you can bind an event to capture the tab press, and cancel it:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 9 && !$(event.target).closest('.model').length) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

To give you the ability to add/ remove the event handler at will, it will be easier to do it like so:

```
function stopTab(event) {
    if (event.which === 9 && !$(event.target).closest('.model').length) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

$(document).bind('keydown', stopTab); // to add
$(document).unbind('keydown', stopTab); // to remove
```

Your modal dialog must have a class of `modal` for this to work (or simply alter the selector).

Comment: yeah you are right , thats what i mentioned too , its quick and easy too.

Comment: this doesnt prevent the user from tabbing over behind the div and using the controls via keyboard

Comment: @mkoryak , is it ,,thanks for telling us new thing , then its better to use dialog or block UI